# Run two programs and handling I/O by Java server

Tags: java, memory-management, io, runtime.exec

I have two programs ( the language doesn't matter, let's say C++ ) and i have to run and manage the communication between them ( by a server written in Java ) this communication works as follow :

At each step program #1 gets input from the program #2 and after doing some processing on it, it'll create an output and gives it to the program #2 as its input and program #2 do the same thing. After a few steps ( could be like 10 steps ) this communication will be over. there's no delay between these steps and they work immediately.

I've run them through `java.lang.Process` and for handling the input and output, I'm using `InputStream` and `OutputStream`.
The problem is, I have no control over these Programs behavior, So they could **damage my server**, intentionally or unintentionally, like consuming all the Memory or crashing the entire server.

How can I handle these behaviors and protect my server from crashing ? Is there a better way to do this ?